Items inside border does not resize when window resolution changes
I was wondering if there is an option to make the items inside the border resize when the window changes its size.
This is what I mean:

Original
What I get

<Window x:Class="PortableISO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PortableISO"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,47" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="101,73,101,73">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="392" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="598">
                    <Grid x:Name="UserIn" Margin="299,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Label Content="Welcome" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                        <Label Content="Website and version" Height="24" Margin="10,35,173,323" Width="116"/>
                        <Label Content="Do you agree with the terms?" Height="26" Margin="10,64,119,292" Width="170"/>
                        <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="222" Margin="15,95,0,65" Width="279">
                            <FlowDocument>
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </FlowDocument>
                        </RichTextBox>
                        <Button Content="Button" Height="38" Margin="45,328,173,16" Width="81"/>
                        <Button Content="Button" Height="38" Margin="177,328,41,16" Width="81"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Image Height="134" Margin="67,129,384,129" Width="147" Source="/logo.png"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>


I am trying to know if its possible to make the items change dynamically as it will be run on fullscreen with different resolutions in WinPE.
I am trying to make the items have the correct size

"window resolution" in the title is confusing. You just maximized your window and thus window size changed? Or you changed the screen resolution and thus the resultion of windows in that screen changed?

The windows resolution is the window size, I can have the window size of 1280 x 720 which equates to a 720p resolution monitor. I just need to know how to make the things inside the grid change dynamically accroding to the window size like my border.

Any time you use "huge" Margins, you have to ask yourself: "What am I doing wrong?" Margins and Paddings (of more than say "4-16"; the width of a scrollbar) "cramp" available space when you should be using "layout controls"; e.g. Grids; StackPanels; etc. The way you're working, you should use a "ViewBox", to get everything back to (normal) "scale".

There is an option to make the items resize when the window changes its size. But to achieve this, you need to change the way you think about layout. And also the way you design it.
For e.g. HorizontalAlignment="Center" means "If there is more space than needed then keep object in center, do not resize it.". So if you directly instruct WPF to not to resize an object, don't expect it will be resized.
Another mistake here is to set Width or Height directly. If you says Width="81" don't expect it will be different than 81. To make it responsible do not use Width or Height. Let the container (like Grid) decide about sizes of elements.
Positioning elements using margins (like Margin="10,64,119,292") is also an error. Don't do that like this, it's bad. Instead define more rows/columns in Grid and place elements in a right cells. Don't forget there are properties like Grid.RowSpan and Grid.ColumnSpan that allows you to merge cells.
In short: you started to design the layout in a really wrong way. Now you have to fix everything to make it scale with available space.

I agree with Sinus32 about the way to lay out elements.
Apart from it, the simple solution is wrapping the content in a ViewBox.
<Window ...>
    <ViewBox>
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </ViewBox>
</Window>

